# Save NSFetchResultsController cache after killing the app

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am working on a Core Data project which handles more than 150000 records. The records are displayed in a table view using a NSFetchedResultsController. The records are to be sorted using different attributes of my entity.

To make the app feel fast, I have created multiple `NSFetchedResultsController`s with different sort descriptors, to show the corresponding sorted results. I initialise the FRCs when my app launches and keep the users waiting till the FRCs are initialised. After that, when the user changes the sort key, i just replace the current FRC with the one for the new sort key, and hence sorting *feels* instantaneous.

The app works fine when it is in the RAM. But it takes around 15-20 secs (iPad 1) to initialise when killed and restarted.

Is there is a way to save the FRCs' cached data to the disk when the app quits and restore when the app is relaunched? Or is there a better workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Uhm...if you specify a cache name an NSFetchedResultController should already have been saved to disk, so I think much depends on how you initialize the controller.

Anyway all the fetched controller caches are saved into

"AppSandbox"/Library/Caches/.CoreDataCaches/SectionInfoCaches/

and I don't think they get deleted after shutting down the app.
Try to play with that, you can easily access the Library folder with:

```
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

But I read that when a controller found a cache with same name as the one with it got initialized it checks if it is still conform and then update it, probably with a huge amount of data a little time is spent with updating cache information.
Think about using NSOperation to load fetched controller and speed up things.
Maybe starting with the default one that get displayed most.

Comment: Thanks for the location of the cache files. But only some of the FRCs caches are stored on the disk (they are persistent across app launches). Also I don't see any noticeable difference between searching when starting the app for the first time or killing and relaunching it. I think loading the cache during app startup may not be the best thing out. I should look for something else. I am already using GCD for asynchronous fetches.